# Is there any method to combine the pair inside array to form a new array in java script

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to arrange any kind of array input into a sorted array that also combines the equal pairs into an array inside the same array.

I do the following

```
const arrangeTheArray=(arr)=>
   {
      //checking input here 
        if(arr.length<2)
        {
          return arr;
        } else {
      //sorting the array
        arr= arr.sort();
        }
     //displaying the sorted array
        console.log(arr);
        for(let i=1; i<arr.length;i++)
        {
          for(let j=0;j<i;j++)
           {
            //here I am looping and comparing the values of array 
             if(arr[j]===arr[i]){
            //putting the value
             arr[j]= [arr[i],arr[j]];   
             }
          }
        }
         //displaying the final output
          console.log(arr);
}
arrangeTheArray([0,2,2,1,1,6,3,1,0])
```

e.g array input : `[0,2,2,1,1,6,3,1,0]`
                final out put: `[[0,0],[1,1,1],[2,2],3,6]`

Comment: your sorting goes wrong for numbers greater then `9`,  becaus ou are sorting strings and not numbers.

Comment: Sometimes I really mess up with logic so by doing sort(a,b=>return a-b)method would it solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [**map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Here idea is

- First create a object with each digit as key and group the values by key.
- Now map on the grouped data, if the length of element greater than one pass element as it is, else pass the 0th index value

```js
let combine = (arr) =>{
  let groups =  arr.reduce((op,inp)=>{
    op[inp] = op[inp] || []
    op[inp].push(inp)
    return op
  },{})
  let final = Object.values(groups).map(e=> e.length > 1 ? e : e[0])
  return final
}

console.log(combine([0,2,2,1,1,6,3,1,0]))
```

```js
const arrangeTheArray=(arr)=>{
    if(arr.length<2)
    {
      return arr;
    } else {
      arr = arr.sort((a,b)=>a-b);
    }
    let final = []
    for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
      let current = arr[i]
      let j = i;
      let temp = []
      while(arr[j] === current){
        temp.push(arr[j])
        j++
      }
      i = j-1
      temp = temp.length > 1 ? temp : temp[0]
      final.push(temp)
    }
  console.log(final)
}
arrangeTheArray([0,2,2,1,1,6,3,1,0])
```

Comment: Well Thank you so much for your answer it is giving the desired output.I am facing little difficulties in understanding your code though. Can you tell me if I can achieve the same output using my code instead

Comment: @jsLearner you can tell me where you're facing problem to understand will help you. wait let me update question with your version too

Comment: I gotta read and understand reduce properly. I was trying to achieve that with just arrays and for loop. So far i was able to sort the array and even manager to combine few pairs but that does not give the correct answer for all the inputs

Comment: @jsLearner i have added one with for and while loop you can see. let me know if you find any difficulty

Comment: This works however the best answer should be the first way you mentioned

Comment: @jsLearner `map` `filter` and `reduce` are very handy methods you should learn them :) `MDN` is best place to start

Comment: map and filter i knew but could not think if we can use it here...gotta work on programming logic alot I am still learning

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.reduce` to accumulate the common elements in an object.

Then use `Object.values` and `Array.from` to process the nested arrays into arrays of common elements and distinct elements:

```js
const arrangeTheArray = (arr) => {
  if (!Array.isArray(arr) && arr.length < 2){
    return arr;
  }
  const pairs = arr.reduce((acc, ele) => {
      if(acc[ele]){
        acc[ele].push(ele);
      }else{
        acc[ele] = [ele];
      }
      return acc;
  }, {});
  return Array.from(Object.values(pairs), ele => ele.length > 1 ? ele : +ele.join())
 }
 
 console.log(arrangeTheArray([0,2,2,1,1,6,3,1,0]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could sort the array with a callback for numbers and reduce the array by checking the predecessor `p` and the actual value `v` and push either the value or an array of the last group and the value.

```js
function arrangeTheArray(array) {
    return array
        .sort((a, b) => a - b)
        .reduce(
            (r, v, i, { [i - 1]: p }) => r.concat([p !== v ? v : [].concat(r.pop(), v)]),
            []
        );
}

console.log(arrangeTheArray([0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 6, 3, 1, 0]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With a classsic `while` loop from the end, because the array shrinks.

```js
function arrangeTheArray(array) {
    var i = array.length - 1;
    array.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    while (i--) {
        if (array[i] === (Array.isArray(array[i + 1]) ? array[i + 1][0] : array[i + 1])) {
            array[i] = [].concat(array[i], ...array.splice(i + 1, 1));
        }
    }
    return array;
}

console.log(arrangeTheArray([0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 6, 3, 1, 0]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: this looks good, thanks for the answer gotta read the reduce method once. But can we do it with for loop as well the one which I am trying ?